# Accessing Image Source as Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a photo gallery in React. So far I have an App component and a Photo component. The details for my images lives in the App components state, and I want to pass the images down to the Photo component. So far, so good.

However, when I try to assign the `<img />` tag the appropriate source using the image props, it doesn't work. I'm doing this by `<img src={ this.props.images.src } />`. When I log it to the console, the value is undefined.

What's going on?

Code for the App component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Photo from './components/Photo';
import images from './data/images';
import './App.css';
import './css/Photo.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      images: images,
      visible: false,
      modalClass: 'photo-modal-invisible'
    };
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    const isVisible = this.state.visible;

    if(isVisible === false) {
      this.setState({ visible: true, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-visible', activeImage: images[index] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ visible: false, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-invisible' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="photo-container">
            {
              this.state.images.map((image, index) =>
                <Photo
                  images={ this.state.images }
                  visible={ this.state.visible }
                  modalClass={ this.state.modalClass }
                />
              )
            }
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Code for the Photo component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './../css/Photo.css';

class Photo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <a href="#"><img src={ this.props.images.src } /></a>
    );
  }
}

export default Photo;
```

Image data:

```js
export default [{
  title: 'Mountain Road',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Mountain Road',
  src: '/assets/images/image1.png'
}, {
  title: 'Fall Forest',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Fall Forest',
  src: '/assets/images/image2.png'
}, {
  title: 'Flower Bridge',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Flower Bridge',
  src: '/assets/images/image3.png'
}, {
  title: 'Dry River',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Dry River',
  src: '/assets/images/image4.png'
}, {
  title: 'Moony Mountains',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Moony Mountains',
  src: '/assets/images/image5.png'
}, {
  title: 'Snowy Mountains',
  photographer: 'Emma Ayers',
  alt: 'Snowy Mountains',
  src: '/assets/images/image6.png'
}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within your `map` method, you are passing in the whole array (`this.state.images`) that you are attempting to map over. You can think of map as a functional `for` loop, so for each image you loop over, you are returning a `<Photo />` and each instance of that loop is one of your objects that you defined within image data file.

```
this.state.images.map((image, index) => (
    <Photo
     image={image} // the fix
     visible={this.state.visible}
     modalClass={this.state.modalClass}
   />
)
```

and then in your `Photo` component

```
<a href="#"><img src={this.props.image.src} /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! That got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass one image to Photo component

```
<React.Fragment>
      <div className="photo-container">
        {
          this.state.images.map((image, index) =>
            <Photo
              image={ image }
              visible={ this.state.visible }
              modalClass={ this.state.modalClass }
            />
          )
        }
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

You don't need to make photo as stateful component. stateless functional component is enough for displaying just view.

```
const Photo (props) => (
      <a href="#"><img src={ props.image.src } /></a>
    );
  }
}

export default Photo;
```

Answer (score 0):

**app component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Photo from './components/Photo';
import images from './data/images';
import './App.css';
import './css/Photo.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: images,
      visible: false,
      modalClass: 'photo-modal-invisible'
    };
  }

  handleClick = (index) => {
    const isVisible = this.state.visible;
    if(isVisible === false) {
      this.setState({ visible: true, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-visible', activeImage: images[index] });
    } else {
      this.setState({ visible: false, visibleClass: 'photo-modal-invisible' });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="photo-container">
            {
              this.state.images.map((image, index) =>
                <Photo
                  images={image}
                  visible={this.state.visible}
                  modalClass={this.state.modalClass}
                  onClick={(index) => this.handleClick(index)}
                />
              )
            }
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**photo component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './../css/Photo.css';

class Photo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <a href="#"><img src={ this.props.images.src alt={this.props.images.alt}} /></a>
    );
  }
}

export default Photo;
```

Here problem was image map function.. While passing the map function argument you are passing the direct state of image array here. So map works as in loop with image array object.

Here for active image, please share the use case so that I can give you better way to handle it.